# After creating a UIView with initWithFrame, how do I change the image?

Tags: iphone, image, uiview

I'm a bit lost here. I have a class subclassed from UIView called BalloonGuy. I initialize it like this.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

UIImage* loadedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"balloonguy.png"];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, loadedImage.size.width, loadedImage.size.height);

self = [super initWithFrame:rect];
image=[loadedImage retain];

self.opaque = YES;
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

return self;
```

}

I add it as a subview and everything is great.

What I can't do, however is change the image afterwards, ever. I won't list my failed attempts but what *do* I do?

Comment: I do not see any code where the image is added to a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to redraw your view when you change your `image` property, so overriding the property setter in this case may be a good idea:

```
- (void) setImage:(UIImage *) im {
   [image release];
   image = nil;
   image = [im retain];
   [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```